# Using Blazor OIDC authentication with Google OAuth only for Google Drive

Tags: google-oauth, blazor, openid-connect

In my Blazor WASM app I am using OIDC authentication to log in to Google Drive as described here:

[Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with the Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[Google Auth error getting access token in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083740/google-auth-error-getting-access-token-in-blazor)

[Cannot log in or get access token with Google Authorization on Blazor WASM Standalone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540754/cannot-log-in-or-get-access-token-with-google-authorization-on-blazor-wasm-stand)

But I don't want to use

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <RedirectToLogin />
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

because I don't want to restrict user access to my Blazor page.

**Most importantly:** I don't want the user to see the "Authorizing..." message for several seconds when they aren't logged in - logging in is optional.

I only need the Google OAuth login if the user decides to use Google Drive, so I can get the access token.

#### How can I use OIDC authentication only to get the access token for Google Drive?

If that isn't possible, can I use C# to login to Google as seen here in JavaScript?

[OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following suggestion may work. If not, report further issues, and I'll try to improve on it...

Make the following changes in your App.razor file:

Replace:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                               DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
 </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

with

```
<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

You also have to remove all added Authorize attributes.

You'll no longer make use of the `RedirectToLogin` component...
Leave the `LoginDisplay` component in its place to enable authentication when requested.

Comment: If I use RouteView instead of AuthorizeRouteView then I can display the Google login page optionally, but after login, the app displays /authentication/login-callback#state=...&access_token=... with This site can’t be reached 
localhost refused to connect. 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Using `RouteView` instead of `AuthorizeRouteView` works, I had an error in my OAuth config.